# How to make a shopify app/theme extension which would get displayed in the brand's store UI?

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, shopify-template

We have an application which integrates with Shopify Clothing stores. We run our application in an iframe inside the shopify store where it interacts with the store's user.

Right now this application gets integrated with Shopify manually by inserting our script tag inside the store's product page. Can someone tell me how I can do this using a shopify app or theme extension?

**Edit** after David's answer
Is it also possible for me to get information about standard buttons in the theme like the Add to Cart button or Change Variants input. Ideally I would like to get the selector for these.

Answer (score 0):

You would create a Shopify App that asks for permission to write ScriptTags. The Apps simply installs a script tag pointing to your App. So when the merchant installs your App, they get the script tag. Depending on what your App does in that iframe, you may need your Shopify App to provide other support, but that is not detailed in your OP, so I leave it at that.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is it also possible for me to get information about standard buttons in the theme like Add to Cart button, Change Variants input. Ideally I would like to get the selector for these.

Comment: You can ask for theme read permissions, download the theme, and parse it to extract the source code, and using that, decide what the selectors are for the shop.